# How to select 3 largest results, but exclude null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I have two tables (Events and Occurrences). Each event has 0 or more entries in the occurences table. I want to sum the number of occurrences and get the top 5 results back. I have some SQL that works for this as long as all events have entries in the occurrences table. Where there is an event with no entries in the occurrences table, that ends up at the top of the list.

What's the right SQL to achieve this ?

Table definitions

> Event
> id - integer
> EventName - varchar(200)
>
> Occurrences
> id - int
> Event_ID - int
> Timestamp - datetime
> TimesOccurred - int

For an event with ID 1 (Event Name - 'Context Switch'), I might have the corresponding rows in the Occurrences table:

> ID: 1, Event_ID: 1, Timestamp: '2016-08-02 05:52:00', TimesOccurred: 50
> ID: 8, Event_ID: 1, Timestamp: '2016-08-02 07:11:00', TimesOccurred: 20

I would have other events with corresponding entries in the Occurrences table, and some events with no corresponding entries (haven't happened yet, infrequent events, etc.)

The following SQL will give me the top 5 occurring events by summing the TimesOccurred column for all events with the same ID.

```
SELECT Events.Name, t.total as Total FROM Events
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Occurrences.Event_ID, sum(Events.TimesOccurred) as total FROM Occurrences 
INNER JOIN Events on Events.id = Occurrents.Event_ID GROUP BY Events.id) t
on Events.id = t.Event_ID ORDER BY t.total DESC limit 5;
```

This might give me

> Segfault 20
> Context Switch 10

However, if I have an event named OOM with an ID of 3, and there are no entries in the Occurrences table with an Event_ID of 3, I then get the following

> OOM
> Segfault 20
> Context Switch 10

I tried changing my query to:

```
SELECT Events.Name, COALESCE(t.total, 0) as Total FROM Events
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Occurrences.Event_ID, sum(Events.TimesOccurred) as total FROM Occurrences 
INNER JOIN Events on Events.id = Occurrents.Event_ID GROUP BY Events.id) t
on Events.id = t.Event_ID ORDER BY t.total DESC limit 5;
```

This then returns

> OOM 0
> Segfault 20
> Context Switch 10

I believe that this is because I'm ordering on t.total, and COALESC is not setting t.total to 0 where the result is null, but instead returning 0 where the result is null.

Any idea how I can exclude null values from my top 5 occurring events ?

Thanks,

Comment: `sum(Events.TimesOccurred)` ????? TimesOccurred in Occurrences table right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres you could define the treatment of null values in `ORDER BY` clause by adding `NULLS [LAST/FIRST]` after the sort direction.

Also, you only need to visit both tables once - additional derived table is not necessary.

```
SELECT Events.Name, sum(Occurences.TimesOccurred) as Total 
FROM Events
LEFT JOIN Occurrences ON Events.id = Occurrences.Event_ID
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 5
```

From [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html) (**bold emphasis mine** - the reason you were getting nulls in your top 5 query):

> By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null value;
>   that is, **NULLS FIRST is the default for DESC order**, and NULLS LAST
>   otherwise.

If you still need to return 0 when there are no occurencies (because you might have 5 or less events total) then adding `COALESCE()` is the way to go - which you did by the way.

---

I have also added integer aliases to columns in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

You could also make aliases for your table names to shorten the code a little.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you simplify the query and use `NULLS LAST`:

```
  SELECT e.Name, sum(o.TimesOccurred) as total
  FROM Events e LEFT JOIN
       Occurrences o I
       ON Events.id = o.Event_ID
  GROUP BY e.Name
  ORDER BY total DESC NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 5;
```

Notice that only one join between the two tables is needed.